# Can't change single element in 2d list

Tags: python

I want to change only one element in the 2d list. I can change an element in list1 using `list1[0][2] = "x"` but when i do the same for list2 more than one element is changed.

```
list1 = []

for i in range(0,5):
    list1.append(['O']*5)


list2 = [['o','o','o','o','o']]*5
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is 5 copies of *the same list*

```
list2 = [['o','o','o','o','o']]*5
```

Getting a good understanding of when it's ok to use copies of the same reference, and when it's not ok is important to writing efficient code.